# logback show logs with line number

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I want to write log like:

```
2014-04-17 11:00:16.408 [http-apr-9090-exec-4] DEBUG package.method(line) - log.
```

so I config the logback.xml, in the pattern, the config like:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M(%line) - %msg%n
```

Every thing shows ok **except** the line number, and if i add set like

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M %line - %msg%n
```

Then all works. so there must be something wrong with my configuration.
Could anyone help me ? Thanks. I want to display like what I want, and no space between method name and line number.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [Logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) states

> In PatternLayout, parenthesis can be used to group conversion
>   patterns. **It follows that the '(' and ')' carry special meaning and
>   need to be escaped if intended to be used as literals.** The special
>   nature of parenthesis is further explained below.
>
> [...]
>
> If you need to treat the parenthesis character as a literal, it needs
>   to be escaped by preceding each parenthesis with a backslash. As in,
>   `\(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]\)`.

You'll need to escape the parenthesis with a `\`.

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have log messages where you can click on a link into the source code, e.g. in IntelliJ, use the following pattern for console logging inside your IDE:

```
<pattern>
    %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) %magenta([%thread]) %yellow(%logger{40}.%M\(%class{0}.java:%line\)) - %msg%throwable%n
</pattern>
```

Answer (score 5):

A note for anyone who stumbles onto this page looking for how to configure this in the application.properties file, I had success escaping the parenthesis by adding two backslashes.

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M \\(%line\\) - %msg%n
```

Comment: The added backslash isn't for the parenthesis, it's for the first backslash.

Comment: I was unable to track down why I had to use two backslashes. I agree that's what should be happening. Perhaps one of the frameworks involved demanded the extra backslash.

Answer (score 1):

For console logging I use:

```
<Pattern>%black(%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "Europe/London"}) %highlight(%-5level) [%green(%X{sessionId})] %yellow(%logger{36}@%method\(%line\)) - %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
```

And for logging to file:

```
 <pattern>[%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", "Europe/London"}] [${HOSTNAME}] [%thread] %level %logger{36}@%method:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
```